# Throws and throw in same method

Tags: java, exception

I have a method:

```
public List<Model> getModelList() throws ModelNotFoundException {
    if (modelList.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ModelNotFoundException("Model list is empty!");
    }
    return modelList;
}
```

Is it redundant to use throws with throw? If I remove throws ModelNotFoundException, idea underlines throw new ...

Comment: That's how checked exceptions are implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question

> Is it redundant to use throws with throw?

No. It is perfectly valid.

Besides
if `ModelNotFoundException` is an unchecked exception like `NullPointerException`, it is not required to declare with `throws` clause in the method.

if `ModelNotFoundException` is a checked exception like `FileNotFoundException`, it is similar to your code. It means you have to declare it with `throws` and also use `throw` based upon condition.

You may get answers from seniors also about it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `ModelNotFoundException` is checked exception, therefore you should indicate that the method throws that. If you change it to unchecked exception, it will compile.

[Understanding checked vs unchecked exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/understanding-checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java)